# 3d menu error in XNA project

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8, xna-4.0

I am trying to build 3d menu in XNA and it is showing NotImplementedException error. A menu with four buttons to select.Did I miss anything in this project? I am new to XNA. Code is as follows. Thanks in advance.

```
//ModelMenuGame.cs

public class ModelMenuGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        SpriteFont font;
        Model menuItemModel;
        Vector3 cameraPosition;

        Matrix view;
        Matrix projection;
        List<ModelMenuItem> Menu;
        int TotalMenuItems = 4;

        Rectangle LeftRegion;
        Rectangle RightRegion;

        int currentIndex = 0;
        public event EventHandler OnTap;           

        public ModelMenuGame()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
            InactiveSleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        }

         protected override void Initialize()
        {
            cameraPosition = new Vector3(-40, 10, 40);
            view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
            projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
            Menu = new List<ModelMenuItem>();

            LeftRegion = new Rectangle(0, 0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
            RightRegion = new Rectangle(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, 0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);


            OnTap = new EventHandler(Item_OnTap);

            currentIndex = currentIndex % TotalMenuItems;
            if (currentIndex < 0)
            {
                currentIndex = TotalMenuItems - 1;
            }
            else if(currentIndex > TotalMenuItems - 1)
                {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
            foreach (ModelMenuItem item in Menu)
            {
                if (item.Index == currentIndex)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Selected = false;
                }
            }   

            menuItemModel = Content.Load<Model>("ModelMenuItem3D");    
            font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("gameFont");    
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalMenuItems; i++ )
            {
                int X = -20;
                ModelMenuItem item =  new ModelMenuItem(this, menuItemModel, view, projection);

                item.Translation = new Vector3(X + (i * 20), 0, 0);
                item.Index = i;
                Menu.Add(item);
            }
            Menu[0].Selected = true;  
            base.Initialize();
        }

        private void Item_OnTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

       protected override void LoadContent()
        {               
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);    
        }

       protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }    
       protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
           if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();
            Vector2 tapPosition = new Vector2();
            TouchCollection touches = TouchPanel.GetState();
            if (touches.Count > 0 && touches[0].State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
            {
                tapPosition = touches[0].Position;
                Point point = new Point((int)tapPosition.X, (int)tapPosition.Y);

                if (LeftRegion.Contains(point))
                {
                    --currentIndex;
                    OnTap(this, null);

                }
                else if (RightRegion.Contains(point))
                {
                    ++currentIndex;
                    OnTap(this, null);

                }    
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
            GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;

            foreach (ModelMenuItem item in Menu)
            {
                item.Draw();
            }
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font , "Current Index :" + currentIndex.ToString(),new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Erm... are you tapping an item? Causing the delegate to be called here?

```
            if (LeftRegion.Contains(point))
            {
                --currentIndex;
                OnTap(this, null);

            }
            else if (RightRegion.Contains(point))
            {
                ++currentIndex;
                OnTap(this, null);

            }
```

Because OnTap throws an exception everytime.

```
    private void Item_OnTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); //This line throws a NotImplementedException
    }
```

Comment: yes, after tapping this error is coming. but i couldn't find what i was missing;

Answer (score 0):

There actually is no issue, your code worked as expected. If an application catches an error then an exception is thrown, for example an `OutOfBoundsException` or a `NullReferenceException`. You can also throw your own exceptions using the `throw` keyword and a new instance of an error.

That line below explicitly tells you program to throw the error, so if you remove `throw new NotImp...` the error will no longer occur. See below.

To get rid of the error change this:

```
private void Item_OnTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); //This line throws a NotImplementedException
}
```

to this:

```
private void Item_OnTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Put your code here to handle the tap event...
}
```

The `NotImplementedException` is just an initial exception to tell the developer that they need to replace that thrown exception with their own code.